# How to define a column class in R, dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame like this

```
scf0001    123    4567   -  4350
scf0001    4474   4878   +  376  *
scf0002    5375   10571  c  5006
scf0003    11370  16986  c  5536
scf0003    16256  17000  -  789  *
```

when I attempt to read it as a table in R, the error is `line 2 did not have 5 elements`, so it is not recognizing the star(*), I tried to read it as string with `na.string="*"` but it didn't work, so I think I have to define it with `colclasses=`.I tried something like this `colClasses=[, c(6)="character"]` but it doesn't work, `Error: unexpected '['`

Comment: Use `fill = TRUE`

Comment: @akrun this command created a new row for the stars and put them under the first column! e.g.  scf0001    4474   4878   +  376   (first row)                                                              *    NA    NA   NA   NA   NA (second row)